# Add class to Gutenberg main container `is-root-container`

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to build a sidebar plugin in Gutenberg that allows you to upload a background image and some classes to the body. Everything works, except that the js inside the sidebar isn't fired until the sidebar is open. So, no update on page load until you open the sidebar. Since I need to use `is-root-container` in the admin to simulate the body of the front-end, I wanted to know if there's a hook in wordpress where I could add classes and inline style to this Gutenberg div container.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried and more details to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I combed through the internet and chatgpt, tried all sorts of filters and hooks and it appears that the root container is nowhere to be found to properly target its properties.
For now I use the only solution that works for me, which is adding the class to the **`.is-root-container`** div after it is fully loaded.

Example code below (with assumption that the jQuery is loaded - which is always true in the Editor afaik):

```
// The function that adds your custom class.    
function SetRootClass($) {
  setTimeout(function () { // setTimeout because editor is loaded but not yet rendered.
    $('.is-root-container').addClass('your-class'); // add your class to the rendered root container
  });
}

const select = wp.data.select;
const subscribe = wp.data.subscribe;

// Subscribe to data events
const closeListener = subscribe(() => {
  const isReady = select('core/editor').__unstableIsEditorReady();
  if (!isReady) {  // if core editor is not loaded
    return; // bounce
  }  
  closeListener(); // if code editor is loaded, close the subscriber.
  
  SetRootClass(jQuery); // call the class modyfying handler (must be a separate function)
});
```

This is not an ideal solution because it modifies the React app but it will work for 99% of scenarios you will encounter as this DOM element is rarely modified after it's loaded. (i.e. changing preview to Tablet or Mobile with destroy the dom and your class will be gone, you might need more hackery to observe for those scenarios and re-apply your class if needed).